# JmDNS occasionally detects two different devices with same IP address

Tags: java, android, ip, mdns, jmdns

I'm working on an android app which discovers devices from local network by JmDNS, most of the time, it just works fine, but I found **JmDNS** would occasionally detect two different devices with same IP address from the log.

Comment: These things happen. You have to restart those devices.

Comment: I'm not a network expert, but I still believe this doesn't make sense, because it just happened within seconds, or even nearly at the same time according to my log. Maybe it's a bug on JmDNS?